# Rewrite url using .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to add https in a specified url

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^magsonwink.winkplatform.com/Shopping/paynow
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://magsonwink.winkplatform.com/Shopping/paynow%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,L]
```

but this not worked for me. After googling i can't get a specified answer. if any one know about this please help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable is *only* the hostname, no URL-path info is in it. So you need to remove it and add it to the pattern in your rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^magsonwink.winkplatform.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?Shopping/paynow(.*)$ https://magsonwink.winkplatform.com/Shopping/paynow$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the corrected code:

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^magsonwink\.winkplatform\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^Shopping/paynow(?:/.*|)$ http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

- Above code will work both with HTTP and HTTPS
- No need to use QSA flag since you aren't modifying query string